# Thomas algorithm for 3D finite difference

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-analysis, finite-difference, linear-solver

For 1D finite difference, the resulting linear system is tri-diagonal and can be solved in `O(n)` using the [Thomas algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm).

I am trying to solve a finite difference system in 3D. [Numerical Methods](http://www.techmat.vgtu.lt/~inga/Files/Quarteroni-SkaitMetod.pdf) by Quarteroni et al goes over some theory behind extending the Thomas algorithm to block linear systems. This method seems to be ideal for me because it is still `O(n)`.

From an algorithmic point of view however, I'm not sure how to proceed. Is there a reference that covers the implementation of this algorithm for a linear system such as the one resulting from 3D finite difference?

Comment: The point of Thomas algorithm, which is really just a special-cased GE/LU for a tridiagonal matrix, is that a tridiagonal matrix has tridiagonal LU decomposition. But a 3d finite difference matrix *wouldn't* have a tridiagonal LU decomposition, it would be $n^2$-banded.

Comment: Right, it would be a banded matrix so of course the algorithm wouldn't be identical. The reference I posted (section 3.8) goes over some variations for banded systems. I'm just trying to work out the implementation.

Comment: What is your objective? If it is to compute a solution to your equations with minimal CPU time, I suggest you simply call the Lapack routine dgbsv in a high-performance implementation of Lapack/BLAS  (e.g. OpenBLAS or MKL) and be done with it.

Comment: What PDE do you want to solve? For diffusion problems, you might be able to use alternating-direction-implicit (ADI) methods. It would allow to apply Thomas algorithm to 3D problems (at the cost of being restricted to 2nd order spatial accuracy.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that 2d and 3d discretizations are not block tridiagonal. The only tridiagonal decomposition would be a 2x2 decomposition that encompasses the entire matrix.

Of course, this fact is a great pity. If there *was* a tridiagonal decomposition, we would have a way of getting an $O(N)$ algorithm from a purely algebraic perspective (i.e., by just looking at the matrix). Instead, the only way to get $O(N)$ algorithms are ones that employ multigrid methods that take into account *where the matrix actually comes from*.

Comment: I misunderstood something in the reference. Thank you for clearing that up.